# Big pipe and behaviors context

Tags: 8, javascript

I have problem with drupal behaviors and context in combination with big pipe. It seems like `context` variable sometimes contains same part of page. I have tried:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myCustomBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      console.log(context);
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

When I load page and watch browser console contexts there is `div` with main menu block but there is also whole `#document` element which contain menu block also (see screen).

### [image: context in browser console]

This behaviour is for me real problem because I use [zurb foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/) and I have to initialize all components and I do it:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myCustomBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(context).foundation();
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

I think this is correct way how to initialize foundation for all elements and it should be compatible with big pipe. But if I get same html part in context twice (some sub elements in context are same) I initialize some zurb foundation plugin twice (see next image).

[image: plugin inited multiple times]

This breaks zurb foundation plugins. I'm not sure what to do. I read lot of Drupal documentation about js, behaviours and big pipe and according to documentation there should not be problem.

When I disable big pipe everything works as expected but that's not solution.

Do anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should it be attached with .once?

Comment: I tried it but result was same. I think that once doesn't solve it because two contexts would still contain same elements so even if it would be called once for each context it would be still fired twice for same elements.

Comment: You need to use $.once(). "two contexts would still contain same elements so even if it would be called once for each context it would be still fired twice for same elements" <- This is incorrect. The point of $.once() is that it only fires once, even when (and because) the same HTML elements may be part of the context more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, using once:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.foundationInit = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(body, context).once('foundation-init').each(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.foundationInit = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (document === context) {
        $(document, context).foundation();
      }
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: Can you explain your code?

Comment: You might want to add some extra description here to answer the question, _Do anybody knows what am I doing wrong?_ (e.g what is `if (document === ...` doing that solves the problem)