# Run javascript before Big Pipe

Tags: javascript

I have a page with multiple blocks loaded asynchronously by the Big Pipe module.
I'd like to be able to run some javascript code (in my case, open an ajax popup) immediately after the page is loaded.
The thing is my javascript code (included the standard way, attached to Drupal.behaviors as a library) is executed after all the Big Pipe blocks are loaded, which takes several seconds.

I was able to reproduce this behavior from a fresh Drupal 9 install (standard) with the [Big Pipe Demo](https://www.drupal.org/project/big_pipe_demo) module and a custom module whose only role is to include a JS file with an alert() (inside a Drupal.behavior). As expected, the alert is not displayed until the Big Pipe Demo blocks are loaded.

Any idea how I could run some JS before the Big Pipe blocks starts loading ?

EDIT :
The only "solution" I found so far is to put my JS outside Drupal behaviors and inside a setTimeout so the needed DOM is (hopefully) loaded when the code is executed... I hope I can find a less dirty way of solving this issue !

Comment: Have you tried with your library loaded in the header rather than the footer? I.e. [How to force a JavaScript library to load in the <head> of a Drupal 8 page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/213364/48114)

Comment: Drupal behaviors runs for each part of the DOM loaded. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252257/big-pipe-and-behaviors-context. If this is not about attaching you can use other javascript events.

Comment: @sonfd Thank you but it does not change anything.

Comment: @4k4 You are right, I probably don't need to rely on drupal behaviors. However because I want to fire a popup, I need to interact with the DOM. I tried to respond to DOMContentLoaded but it fires after BigPipe blocks are loaded.
After multiple tests I was able to run some code before bigpipe by putting it inside a setTimeout, without relying on any event... not really a viable solution :(